# Number of players with most wins in tournament

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$n\geq 2$ tennis players play each other once, and there are no draws. For which $1\leq k\leq n$ is it possible that exactly $k$ players have the (joint) highest number of wins?

For example, $k=1$ is always possible, $k=n$ is possible if and only if $n$ is odd.

For $n=3$, $k=1,3$ are possible.

For $n=4$, $k=1,2,3$ are possible.

Is it true that it's always possible unless $k=n$ for $n$ even or $k=n-1$ for $n$ odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True.

This is equivalent to determine for which $k$, there exist an integer $m$ and a score sequence $(s_1,...,s_n)$ such that $s_j<m$ for all $j\leq{n-k}$ and $s_i=m$ for all $i\geq{n-k+1}$.

We will use Landau's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29#Score_sequences_and_score_sets), which provides a necessary and sufficient condition for $(s_1,...,s_n)$ to be a score sequence.

Note $s_1+\cdots+s_{n-k}={n\choose2}-mk$.

The only inequalities need to be satisfied are ${n-k\choose2}\leq{n\choose2}-mk\leq(m-1)(n-k)$.

From ${n-k\choose2}\leq{n\choose2}-mk$, we get $m\leq{n-\dfrac{k}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2k}}$, so we can take $m$ to be the largest possible integer, i.e. $m=n-\lceil\dfrac{k+1}{2}\rceil$.

Now, ${n\choose2}-mk\leq(m-1)(n-k)$ can be simplified to

$(n-2)(n-k)\geq0$ if $k$ is odd (which is true iff $1\leq{k}\leq{n}$) and

$(n-2)(n-k)\geq{n}$ if $k$ is even (which is true iff $1\leq{k}\leq{n-2}$).